# Consulta Cruzada mySql

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Não estou sabendo muito me expressar mais oque eu preciso é  como posso fazer uma query normal e invertida.
A baixo tenho dois campos um de origem e outro de destino. preciso fazer uma

```
       $origem = $_post["origem"];
       $destino = $_post["destino"];

       SELECT * FROM produtos
       where  origem LIKE ?  AND  destino LIKE ?
       $sql3->bind_param("sssiisssss",  $origem,$destino);
```

Mais oque eu preciso e que ela aceite o vice verso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Campos
<input type="text" name="Origem"> 
<input type="text" name="Destino"> 

Base Origem e Destinos
+----+--------+---------+------+---------+
| id | Origem | Destino | nome |  Valor  |
| 01 |  Rio   | Campos  | R C  | 100,00  |
| 02 |Niteroi |  Rio    | N R  | 200,00  |
| 03 | Macaé  | Campos  | M C  | 300,00  |
| 04 | Centro | Barra   | C B  | 400,00  |
```

Answer (score 2):

A `query` abaixo retorna o que você precisa:

```
SELECT * FROM produtos
WHERE  (origem LIKE ?  OR  destino LIKE ?) AND (origem LIKE ?  OR  destino LIKE ?)
```

A passagem dos parâmetros ficaria assim:

```
$sql3->bind_param("ssss", $origem, $destino, $destino, $origem);
```